# Casting in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, import, casting, hive

In my original data I have a filed type as string , in table I want it in int type. How I can cast it from string to int.
1. While loading data into table or
2. After loaded into table then create new table and convert it.
Please suggest me best practice..

Comment: paste the sample input of your data

Comment: Suppose I have data and I created table with all fields as varchar to avoid conflicts , latter I want load data in actual formate , suppose I have one column ID , now its in varchar in table but actually it is int, while loading I should cast this column or after loading in to original table, shall I create new table with correct column type and load this data in to this new table. Which one is better.

Comment: Here I used second secenari....